# node-hashtable - how to get set of all keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Java it's called the keyset.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-hashtable

how come there is no method to return a list of all the keys?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source there seems to be a method `indexes` which returna a list of the keys.